# Putting 3 inputs to the Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a Student Table, with the column of ID and Name. However,
wanted to use the parameters in the Stored Procedure to get:

```
select * from Student where ID = value;
```

While, I used this code. Could not get the outpur. Moreover, I have
got this error message:

> select * from [Student] where ID = 2 Msg 203, Level 16, State 2,
>   Procedure FindTblName, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 28] The name 'select
>   * from [Student] where ID = 2' is not a valid identifier.

```
create procedure FindTblName 
@tblName varchar(100),
@IDName varchar(10),
@IDValue int 
as
begin 

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from '+ QUOTENAME(@tblName) + ' where ' + @IDName + ' = ' + convert(nvarchar(2),@IDValue)
print @sql 
exec @sql 
end

exec FindTblName @tblName = Student, @IDName = ID, @IDValue = 2;
```

Comment: The formatting of your question is not helping anyone understand it. In addition, your attempt to provide a working script is incorrect as you must separate the batch creating your procedure with the batch that immediately attempts to execute it. In addition, you must pass the first parameter as a string - which you did not do. But your error message implies that you did do this correctly. In short - provide a complete script that others can use. Better yet - just don't do this. Catch-all procedures like this are not a best practice.

Comment: Don't inject your parameters; they're parameters and you should parametrise your queries.

Comment: Smor, Thank you for your reply, I have changed the questions recently. I am sorry for being not clear as it is my first time that asking question. Will work on it to be more precise with my question in the near future. However, If i use one parametr with the varchar(100) for Table Name. It works fine. But When I put more parameters does not give me the output

Comment: Use `EXECUTE sp_executesql`, passing the parameterized query text, parameter declarations, and parameter assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you *must* do something like this then properly quote your object names, and parametrise your parameters. Then pass your object names as a `nvarchar`, not an an unknown "object" type:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.FindTblName @TblName sysname , @IDName sysname, @IDValue int AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TblName) + N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@IDName) + N' = @IDValue;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@IDValue int', @IDValue;

END;
GO

EXEC dbo.FindTblName @TblName = N'Student', @IDName = N'ID', @IDValue = 2;
```